# Symbol for reflecting complex numbers over the imaginary axis

Tags: complex-numbers

A bar or star symbol is used for reflecting in the real axis (i.e. complex conjugate).

Is there a commonly (or not so commonly) used symbol for inverting the sign of the real part (i.e. reflecting in the Im-axis) ?

I'm thinking of a situation in which reflections in the axes are the main concepts. Let's use ~z and z*. In this situation -z wouldn't be a main concept but if needed could be written as -z=~z*. Rather than just make up ~z, I wanted to know if there was already a symbol for this.

Comment: @J.M.: can you make this a 2 symbol answer?

Answer (score 8):

$-\bar{z}$ (or $-z^\ast$ if you're of that persuasion) is fine for your needs; no need for new notation.

---

Edit 9/29/2011:

One [paper](http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~djeffrey/Offprints/shouldi.pdf) refers to the operation $-\bar{z}$ as "paraconjugation" and uses $z^\ast$ for it, but since $z^\ast$ is also often used for conjugation proper, I can't recommend the notation in good conscience. (I was hard-pressed to find other papers using the same term, also.)

Comment: Thanks, but I really am looking for a symbol if it exists. See the edited version of the question.

Comment: None that I know of. It's not a particularly common operation, and whatever gain you may get from compressing to a single symbol may very well be offset by you having to explain the blasted thing anyway.

Comment: It might be worth noting some of the reasons why $\bar{z}$ and $-z$ are so much more common. $-z$ is more convenient because it's the only one of the bunch that's _analytic_ (and in particular, it doesn't flip the orientation of the plane), which means that it has much better properties; e.g., it's differentiable as a complex function. So why $\bar{z}$ over the imaginary-axis flip? I'd say it's because generally we're more interested in the real part of a complex number than its imaginary part, and $\bar{z}$ has a closer relation to that (in particular, the fact that $\bar{r}=r$ for real $r$).

Comment: @Steven: There's also the fact that [unreal roots of polynomials with real coefficients can only come in conjugates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem).

Comment: @Steven: I'd say a main reason to consider $\bar{z}$ is that it's a ring homomorphism.

Comment: Agreed, and those are much better reasons than mine.